# Integration of moodle into another website

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, integration, moodle

I have the following scenario:
[image: Moodle integration architecture]
There's a portal page with some content for authenticated users. The authentication is provided by an OAUTH server. Now there must be the possibility for authenticated users to consume E-learning content (Tin Can and SCORM packages) provided by the Moodle LMS. The plan is to integrate the Moodle installation into the portal by using an `iframe` and crafted links directly to the learning content. The authentication with Moodle would be implemented using an custom authentication plug-in for the OAUTH server to avoid further username/password authentication. The goal is seamlessly optical integration into the portal while using the mighty course tracking and management features of Moodle in the backend.

[image: interface draft for Moodle integration]

However this solution seems somewhat hacky in my eyes and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner option to integrate Moodle learning content into another website without losing the tracking and management features of Moodle.

//EDIT: It seems that LTI could provide a similar solution to this and there's a plug-in for Moodle to make it a LTI provider. But how can I consume the LTI content?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LTI is the ideal solution for this task. 
Moodle has good documentation on integrating LTI content with moodle instance.

You can use 'External tool' type resource. Here is the link for full documentation - https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/External_tool. Using this 'activity' type you can consume LTI compliant content from external webservices. 
This is available from Moodle 2.2 onwards.

For moodle versions > 2.8 you can send grades back to the LMS. This means you can not only host content elsewhere but host tests, assessments and assignments as well.

Here are some examples from moodle's website : https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Using_External_tool